# chrome extension not working for secure sites https

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written a chrome extension, but it doesn't seem to work for https sites. Its currently a background page that injects script into the page. It runs jquery and some libraries too. The only way I've found out so far to do this is to run a background page, and use chrome.tabs.executescript. If anyone knows a better way then that would help too.

I've added permissions to http and https sites, so i thought that would be sufficient. Please can someone help, thanks.

Manifest:

```
 {
  "name": "My First Extension",  
  "version": "1.0",  
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",  
  "background_page": "popup.html",  
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]  
 }
```

popup.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab)  
{  
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading")  
    {  
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, { file: "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" }, null);  
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.min.js" }, null);  
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" }, null);  
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js" }, null);  
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "custom.js" }, null);  
    }  
})  

</script>
```

the file custom.js is where i do my coding.

thanks

Comment: I think Google restricts you from doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding "conent_scripts" to manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "css": ["empty.css"]
    }]
```

You have to specify 'css' or 'file'. In my add-on, scripts are loaded dynamically, so I just use a dummy css file.

See also: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: I've tried that, sadly, that doesn't work. Maybe Blender is right, maybe Google restricts it from running in https sites.
Its a shame because the extension I was writing is a popup that on a hot key say crtl+? havent decided yet, will show a popup where you can type a new url, press enter and it changes the page to that site. It works for non secure sites. It would be really helpful when you do full screen (F11). I was hoping to publish it when I was finished.

Comment: I just inspected my popup and executed `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "alert(document.title);" }, null)` in the console. That worked against a https-site. Have you tried running it from a debugger window? The exception messages are helpfull most time.

Comment: I just tested again with my extension. It seems like I can inject simple scripts. I.e. `debugger;` worked. However, if I inject a more complex set of scripts (jquery, jquery-ui and some custom.js, which shows a popup dialog), it just fails silently. No errors, but nothing happens either.

Comment: Hi, yes mine works with Facebook too. Could you possibly try with your google email box? e.g. https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox - mine doesn't work on that page

Comment: I don't have a gmail account. It works on the signup page though. Most likely the script injection works fine. Maybe the page's JavaScript prevents some events from bubbling up to your handler. Just like my dialog did not work with <frameset>. Did you try to add some `alert('foo');` to `custom.js`?

Comment: @paztulio, ill try that - ill let you know how it goes. thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a problem with dependencies. All calls to executeScript are asynchronous. So you can not assume that jquery is injected when you start injecting jquery hotkeys. You should better use something like this:

```
var runScripts = function(tabId, scripts, cb) {
        var current = scripts.shift();
        if (current) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: current}, function(a) {
                console.log("Finished running script:", current);
                runScripts(tabId, scripts, cb);
            });
        } else {
            cb();
        }
    };

chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css"}, function () {
    runScripts( null, ["jquery.min.js", "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js", "jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js", "custom.js"], function() {}); 
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but I think the answer is what you mentioned before which is when the site is complex - and has framesets in it. My extension does work with https, its just that google mail has frames in the site.

Comment: I thought so. I assume that jquery-hotkeys-plugin / your custom.js does not work with framesets. I have to admit that I am not very savvy with frames as I always tried to avoid them.
Anyhow, I think you will have to append the handler to each frame instad of $("body").